# How can I return actual value of model's object after that value was changed but didn't saved?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

For example I've changed value of Post's object and it didn't pass validation:

```
my_post = Post.last
my_post.name
# => "foobar"

my_post.name = "something wrong"
my_post.save
# => (0.1ms)  begin transaction
# => (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
# => false
my_post.name
# => "something wrong"
```

The actual value is still "foobar", but how can I return it now, without creating a new object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`changes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) returns a hash of the changes made to a model object:

```
my_post.changes["name"][0]  #=> "foobar"
```

This can also be accessed via the dynamically-generated method:

```
my_post.name_change[0]
```

in your case you should do

```
my_post.name = my_post.name_was unless my_post.save
```

More on this is available in the documentation for [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Comment: Also, to go straight to the old value, more directly, you can call my_post.name_was